# Parallel requests with map and for loop with promise.all and then

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise, fs

I am trying to run parallel requests to a third party API for hundreds of keywords and with five different types of request on each, it's working but after the promises resolve I have to manipulating the data further and sometimes it comes a bit earlier.

```
const myFunc = async () => {

  const keywords = ['many', 'different', 'type', 'of', 'keywords']

  // Create promise's array      
  let promises = keywords.map((keyword, index) =>
    new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
      for (let page = 1; page <= 5; page++) 
        resolve(request(keyword, page))
      }, index * 100)
   ))

  // Resolve
  await Promise.all(promises).then(() => { 
    // Here is where I hope to be dealing with the fully resolved data to read and write the file 
  })
}
```

The request function calls the API and then appends the result to a csv file, what I would like to do is when the last promise has been appended to the file, I would like to read that file and manipulated its data, is at this point I am having problems I the csv gets malformed.

I could be down to the way I use `fs` after should it be sync or async not sure, but would like to know if there is something wrong with this approach on parallel requests.

Any help would be appreciated, many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need *two* `Promise.all`s - one inside the loop in the `new Promise`, and one outside waiting for all requests to finish:

```
const delay = ms =>  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
const pageCount = 5;
const myFunc = async () => {
  const keywords = ['many', 'different', 'type', 'of', 'keywords']
  const promises = keywords.map((keyword, index) =>
    delay(index * 100 * pageCount).then(() => Promise.all(Array.from(
      { length: pageCount },
      (_, i) => delay(100 * (i + 1)).then(() => request(keyword, i + 1))
    )))
  );
  await Promise.all(promises).then(() => { 
    // Here is where I hope to be dealing with the fully resolved data to read and write the file 
  })
}
```

Since every call needs to be preceeded by another delay, it might be easier to use a `for..of` loop:

```
const delay = ms =>  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
const pageCount = 5;
const myFunc = async () => {
  const keywords = ['many', 'different', 'type', 'of', 'keywords']
  for (const keyword of keywords) {
    for (let page = 1; page <= 5; page++) {
      await delay(100);
      await request(keyword, page);
    }
  }
  // Here is where I hope to be dealing with the fully resolved data to read and write the file
};
```

Comment: Many thanks. The resolve argument inside the first promise.all is not being use thou, also the `i` starts from 0 I believe where  as in the code I needed to start form 1

Comment: Oops, you're right, the `new Promise` doesn't do anything, all the needed Promise constructions can be created via the `delay` function. Arrays in Javascript are zero-indexed, so `i` starts at 0 with `Array.from`, but the `(i + 1)` part increments it by 1, like your original code was doing.

Comment: But I needed to be 1 for the request function not so much for the setTimeout, the `page` argument on the request was the `i`, I fixed it by adding `request(keyword, (i + 1)))`

Comment: Actually now when I do a heavy batch the delay does not speed things down and I get `EADDRNOTAVAIL`

Comment: Are you trying to put a delay between *every* call of `request`? Eg, with 3 pages, request page 1, delay 100, request page 2, delay 100, request page 3, delay 100, request next keyword page 1, delay 100, etc? Or something else?

Comment: I need to somewhere otherwise node responds with  `code: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL` after a few hundreds, it goes too fast the timeout is not having any effect in the frequency of the requests

Comment: How do you want the delays to be? Do you want the method I mentioned, or something else?

Comment: The method you suggest seems to be delaying the for loop for the 5 additional requests per keyword but not each keyword

Comment: Right, it's kind of backwards from what your original code was doing, which sent out a request for every keyword at once. Do you want the delay logic I was suggesting, or do you need something else?

Comment: Basically the idea is to do as many requests as possible without getting knocked out of the server, to be fine tuned by the delay

Comment: Sure, but I have no idea what the server is or what sort of delay logic it requires, or what sort of logic you want to implement for this

Comment: The delay logic can clearly be determine by increasing or decreasing the time delay, right? I don't really mind the approach logic, I just want to make as many requests as possible, I will then control the delay to make sure is as fast as it can, but with your code the delay does not slow down even a bit  each request, I mean I want parallel but with a bit of time in between not to choke node

Comment: You can put another before the `Promise.all`. where the number passed is a multiple of the number of keywords. Eg, with 5 keywords, it's `delay(0)` before the first keyword batch, `delay(500)` before the second keyword batch, `delay(1000)` before the third, etc.

Comment: Yes, I actually did that
const promises = keywords.map((keyword, index) =>
    new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(delay(150 * index).then(() =>
           Promise.all(
              Array.from({ length: pages }, (_, i) => 
                request(keyword, (i + 1))
            ))
          )
        }, index * 150))

Comment: The outer delay needs to be longer. Eg if the inner delay is a multiple 150, the outer delay should be a multiple of 750 (if there are 5 keywords)

Comment: But that's why I multiplying it by index

Comment: Oh, right, they're both of length 5 in the example, I got mixed up. Probably best to put it into a single variable beforehand to avoid confusion